# hosting two public facing website on single ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I am trying to host 2 website xxx.com and yyy.com on a single amazon ec2 instance.

So far this is what I have done.

Created ec2 instance with Ubuntu and set up apache, mysql & Php

On Ec2 I have added 2 elastic IP address and associate them with my primary private IP address and secondary private IP address.

Using amazon route53 I have added “A” records for each domain to point to its Elastic IP address.

And lastly created virtual host conf file in apache and activate those site. The conf file looks like below:

```
    ServerName xxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com
    ServerAdmin my email address
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/xxx.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/xxx.com/logs/access.log combined
```

After all this it’s still not working.

For first website it says “Google Chrome could not load the web page because www.xxx.com took too long to respond. The website may be down or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.

For second website it’s still going to its domain name registrar’s home page (even after setting NS records)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you using apache2? (if you're not sure, run `sudo service apache2 status`)

Comment: Yes its apache2 on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Apache 2, your `/etc/apache2/` directory should have a `sites-available` directory inside of it. This is where you want to configure your sites. You'll create a file for each of your sites that looks something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com
    ServerAdmin my email address
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.com/public_html

    ErrorLog /var/www/xxx.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/xxx.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, you'll configure Apache to accept virtual hosts for requests coming in on port 80:

```
...
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
...
```

(`Listen 80` should already be in `ports.conf`; I included it to show where in the file to put the `NameVirtualHost`, although the position doesn't actually matter)

Lastly, run `a2ensite` on each of your virtual hosts to enable them. `a2ensite` takes as its argument the name of the site configuration file. So, for example, if you had `/etc/apache2/sites-available/xxx.com` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/yyy.com`, you'd do `a2ensite xxx.com` and `a2ensite yyy.com`.

Then all you need to do is reload the Apache configuration with `service apache2 reload`, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: HI Thanks for your detailed reply. This is exactly how I set it up in first place but interestingly the first domain xxx.com is working but for second domain it still not.

Comment: HI Thanks for your detailed reply.This is exactly how I set it up but only the first domain xxx.com is working not the second one.I was wondering do I need to set virtualhost based on private IP address because both websites are on the same ec2 server and server has two private ip address.also the box has two elastic IPS which are mapped to its two private IP and I have used this two elastic IP address to map to "A" record of the domain. SO i think request is hitting to its elastic ip and then apache can have VH set up using its private internal IP. any thoughts?any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmm - unfortunately I have no experience with having multiple IPs per machine, so I can't say from experience. However, I'd guess that you may be right about having to specify not only what domain the request is for, but also what IP it's for (or maybe just IP and not domain) - I'd toy around with that and see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a website on each private IP you have then in the Apache Virtual Host configuration you need to specify the Private IP that website should listen on.

For example assuming you have the following scenario

```
Elastic IP 1 -- Mapped to -- x.x.x.1 Private IP
Elastic IP 2 -- Mapped to -- x.x.x.2 Private IP

Site 1 -- using Elastic IP 1 as A record 
Site 2 -- using Elastic IP 2 as A record
```

In the Virtual Host Configuration Specify the IP address you want to bind to

For example: Site 1

```
 <VirtualHost x.x.x.1:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
 <VirtualHost>
```

Site 2:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.2:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
 <VirtualHost>
```

Please use the rest of the configuration as per your requirements.

With this configuration - apache will route

> requests hitting on Elastic IP 1 to Private IP 1
>
> Requests hitting on Elastic IP 2 to Private IP 2

You must have both the Private IP active on EC2 instance